# Xcode & Flutter lottie png：Target debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: Exception: Failed to codesign

Tags: xcode, flutter, lottie

My Project is created with Objective and Dart（Flutter）, I Run my project with Xcode.

Today I want to use [lottie 1.4.3](https://pub.dev/packages/lottie/example)，Because My colleague made the animation with After Effect，She gives me a json file and two pictures.

But After I add the pictures to my Flutter Assets，I cannot compile the project.

I did these,

- 1）detele  `/Users/didi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
- 2）cmd + shift + K to clean Xcode
- 3）at Flutter Files： flutter clean,  flutter pub get

but it didn't work.

```
rsync -av --delete --filter - .DS_Store /Users/kkmac/development/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework /Users/kkmac/Documents/kkFlutterProject/20220928_3/kk_flutter/.ios/Flutter/engine
building file list ... done

sent 1349 bytes  received 20 bytes  2738.00 bytes/sec
total size is 150250055  speedup is 109751.68
♦ /Users/kkmac/development/flutter/bin/flutter --verbose assemble --no-version-check --output=/Users/kkmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/kkProject-iOS-bygjllcqytvkscgjwxovvmcdqyss/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ -dTargetPlatform=ios -dTargetFile=lib/main.dart -dBuildMode=debug -dIosArchs=arm64 -dSdkRoot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk -dSplitDebugInfo= -dTreeShakeIcons=false -dTrackWidgetCreation=false -dDartObfuscation=false -dEnableBitcode= --ExtraGenSnapshotOptions= --DartDefines= --ExtraFrontEndOptions= -dCodesignIdentity=6F8C8A5F5F57490A4515A1BEF6D255E20BBD71E9 debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets
[ +145 ms] executing: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
[  +43 ms] Exit code 0 from: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
[   +3 ms] hw.optional.arm64: 1
[   +8 ms] executing: [/Users/kkmac/development/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +29 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 18116933e77adc82f80866c928266a5b4f1ed645
[   +1 ms] executing: [/Users/kkmac/development/flutter/] git tag --points-at 18116933e77adc82f80866c928266a5b4f1ed645
[  +86 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at 18116933e77adc82f80866c928266a5b4f1ed645
[   +1 ms] 2.5.3
[  +12 ms] executing: [/Users/kkmac/development/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +17 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/Users/kkmac/development/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +14 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +91 ms] executing: [/Users/kkmac/development/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +29 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[   +9 ms] executing: sw_vers -productName
[  +33 ms] Exit code 0 from: sw_vers -productName
[   +1 ms] macOS
[        ] executing: sw_vers -productVersion
[  +27 ms] Exit code 0 from: sw_vers -productVersion
[   +1 ms] 12.3
[        ] executing: sw_vers -buildVersion
[  +21 ms] Exit code 0 from: sw_vers -buildVersion
[        ] 21E230
[  +65 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +133 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'PubDependencies' is not required, skipping update.
[  +65 ms] Initializing file store
[  +13 ms] Done initializing file store
[ +334 ms] Skipping target: debug_unpack_ios
[   +3 ms] Skipping target: gen_localizations
[   +6 ms] Skipping target: gen_dart_plugin_registrant
[ +680 ms] Skipping target: kernel_snapshot
[   +5 ms] Skipping target: debug_universal_framework
[   +1 ms] invalidated build due to missing files: /Users/kkmac/Documents/kkFlutterProject/20220928_3/kk_flutter/DOES_NOT_EXIST_RERUN_FOR_WILDCARD697758133
[  +92 ms] debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets: Starting due to {InvalidatedReasonKind.inputMissing: The following inputs were missing: /Users/kkmac/Documents/kkFlutterProject/20220928_3/kk_flutter/DOES_NOT_EXIST_RERUN_FOR_WILDCARD697758133}
[ +270 ms] Manifest contained wildcard assets. Inserting missing file into build graph to force rerun. for more information see #56466.
[ +163 ms] Persisting file store
[  +11 ms] Done persisting file store
[  +20 ms] "flutter assemble" took 1,846ms.
[ +258 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 255ms
[   +2 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
[   +9 ms] Target debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: Exception: Failed to codesign /Users/kkmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/kkProject-iOS-bygjllcqytvkscgjwxovvmcdqyss/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App.framework/App with identity 6F8C8A5F5F57490A4515A1BEF6D255E20BBD71E9.
           /Users/kkmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/kkProject-iOS-bygjllcqytvkscgjwxovvmcdqyss/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App.framework/App: replacing existing signature
           /Users/kkmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/kkProject-iOS-bygjllcqytvkscgjwxovvmcdqyss/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App.framework/App: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed

           #0      _signFramework (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/ios.dart:645:5)
           #1      IosAssetBundle.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/targets/ios.dart:512:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      _BuildInstance._invokeInternal (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:836:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterBuildSystem.build (package:flutter_tools/src/build_system/build_system.dart:603:16)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:314:32)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #13     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>

[  +11 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      AssembleCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/assemble.dart:331:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
Failed to package /Users/kkmac/Documents/kkFlutterProject/20220928_3/kk_flutter.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

My Flutter project locates at ：
`/Users/kkmac/Documents/kkFlutterProject/20220928_3/kk_flutter/`

My Lottie Json files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7uh7xdjqq2dztq4/lottery.zip?dl=0

Thanks very much

Comment: Could you please add the code to where you targeted this `.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

Try running without adding the version like this `lottie:` in your `pubspec.yaml`